# How to get link to post on mobile Android SE app

Tags: support, android-app

How do I get the link to a post on the mobile SE app for Android so that I can include it in another post, answer, or comment (using Markdown)?

The only solution I found is choose "open in browser" from "more options" and copy the link from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the "Share" menu and tap "Copy to clipboard".

Or just use one of the other sharing options there, if that's what you're looking to do.

> [image]
>
> [image]